# Error when wrapping code in "while" loop

Tags: windows, powershell

OK, I am a little embarrassed but I gotta ask anyway. I have a perfectly-running script that I wrapped in an infinite loop with a sleep at the end:

```
    while($true){}
```

That's all I added was this code and all of the curly braces match so why am I getting this error:

"Missing closing statement block in line x, where x is the last line in the file"

```
function A(){

}

while($true){

  [... Do Stuff ...]
  Start-Sleep -s 10
}
```

I remove the encapuslating while{} and all is fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the syntax posted is correct.

My guess is you retyped this into the browser, I would check all your ( ) to make sure you dont have { } in there by mistake.

Otherwise, need to copy and paste your actual code.